# Beaglebone Android Speaker issues

Tags: android

I recently created an app that is basically a midi controller. You press a button and it outputs a sound. The app works fine on eclipse and works perfectly fine. We flashed jellybean onto a Beaglebone LCD3 cape touchscreen and downloaded the app onto the beaglebone. It loads and you can click the buttons but no sound is outputted. Even if I connect a speaker, nothing is outputting.  Thank you in advance for your time.

```
final MediaPlayer ButtonSound1 = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.button_sound);

final MediaPlayer ButtonSound2 = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.airplane);
final MediaPlayer ButtonSound3 = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.chainsaw);
final MediaPlayer ButtonSound4 = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.midnight);
final MediaPlayer ButtonSound5 = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.jungle);
final MediaPlayer ButtonSound6 = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.river);
final MediaPlayer ButtonSound7 = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.jingle_bell);
final MediaPlayer ButtonSound8 = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.crunch);
final MediaPlayer ButtonSound9 = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.bomb);


derp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
derp2= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
derp3= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
derp4= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
derp5= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
derp6= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
derp7= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);
derp8= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button8);
derp9= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button9);


derp.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        ButtonSound1.start();


    }
});
```

Comment: Will the beaglebone actually play sound by any other means?  Could be a bad device.  Regardless, we're going to need to see some code if there's any hope of troubleshooting this.

Comment: it should be able to connect to a speaker. I guess my question is is this a code issue or a hardware issue? Yea I just looked it up and it should definitely connect to other speakers

Comment: If the device can play sound using some other mechanism besides your program, the problem is probably in your code.  If the device won't play sound at all, I'd say that it's a problem with the device.

Comment: im really new to this and it seems my code wont be posted properly how can i link my apk file?

Comment: Indent the pasted code four spaces, or highlight it and click the `{}` button at the top edge of the editor window.  Don't post a large wall of code; we're not a comprehensive troubleshooting service.

Comment: the rest of the code follows the end part exactly the same is there a line of code I need to add?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I assume you're using either the BeagleBone AUD or DVID-02 capes to give you speaker interface support. If you're using something else, my answer won't fit your situation.

Android uses ALSA in the Linux kernel to support the sound API you're invoking. The kernel requires additional code to understand how to pass sound data across the general purpose I/O pins used by BeagleBone capes.  The jellybean image (Aug 2012) does not have the proper ALSA kernel code to drive the BeagleBone audio capes.

There are a number of patches floating around the Internet for other Linux distributions (notably the [Angstrom distribution](http://www.angstrom-distribution.org/)) which allow this hardware to work ... but they have not yet been ported to the rowboat Android source.